# Can you set a variable using multiple registry searches?

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

When a WiX bootstrapper uses many RegistrySearch-es to set the same variable, such as:

```
<util:RegistrySearch Id='NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVELSearch' Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5" Value="SP" Variable="NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL" />
<util:RegistrySearch Id='NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVELSearchWin64' Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5" Value="SP" Variable="NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL" Win64="yes" />
<util:RegistrySearch Id='NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVELSearchWow64' Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5" Value="SP" Variable="NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL" />
<util:RegistrySearch Id='NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVELSearchWin64Wow64' Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5" Value="SP" Variable="NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL" Win64="yes" />
<Chain>
    ...
    <ExePackage ... InstallCondition="NOT NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL"/>
    ...
</Chain>
```

If one search succeeds but a later one fails, it will reset the variable. Example:

```
...
Setting string variable 'NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL' to value '1'
Setting string variable 'NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL' to value '1'
Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5'
Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5'
...
Condition 'NOT NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL' evaluates to true. <--- FALSE EXPECTED!!!
```

If I were to use a single search, the one that is successful, for example, it will evaluate NOT NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL to false as expected! But how then, can you use multiple RegistrySearch-es to set a single variable, or MUST I use multiple variables for each search?

**Edit**: Normally this is allowed for WiX MSI properties, which is why it is so puzzling to see no support for it in WiX bootstrapper projects or the burn engine.

Comment: You're asking it to search for the SP value under SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5 and store it in NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL.  It's not there so I would expect it to set NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL accordingly.  I think what you want is a 4 registry searches with 4 different variables then use a Condition with AND or OR

Comment: @PeterRitchie Yeah, I had to do this in the end. It seems burn requires a 1-to-1 relationship of searches-to-variables, which is kind of silly because this is actually not the case for WiX MSI projects and properties...where it just won't set a property if it doesn't find it, hence you can map multiple searches to one property (but it could have something to do with how I nest a registry search under a property in WiX whereas here the searches are outside of the variable). If anyone figures out a way to set one variable with multiple searches that would be great.